# Orientation interferes with NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation, navigation-drawer, android-configchanges

I have an app which uses the NavigationDrawer.

I switch fragments like this:

```
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

public void selectItem(int position) { 

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        String fragmentTag = String.valueOf(position);

        FragmentBase fragment = (FragmentBase) fragmentManager
                .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
        if (null == fragment) { 
            fragment = createFragmentByPosition(position);
        }
        if (null == fragment)
            return;

        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_frame, fragment, fragmentTag); 
        }

        if (mCurrentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(mCurrentFragment);
        }
        mCurrentFragment = fragment;
        fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mNoterActivities[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    private FragmentBase createFragmentByPosition(int position) { // FragmentBase just extends Fragment
        FragmentBase fragment = null;

        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = new Fragment1();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

        } else if (position == 1) { // Reminder
            fragment = new Fragment2();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            fragment.setArguments(args);

        }

        return fragment;
    }
```

In the onCreate() method, I do selectItem(0).

I was previously using  `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` for the `Activity`, but I would now like to start creating different layouts for different screen sizes and orientations.  I cannot do this using appropiately named folders if this code is in the manifest.

So, I decided to remove it (I couldn't remember why I had it anyway!).  However, by doing this, whenever the orientation changes, the fragment that is shown is still the same but the action bar changes to another fragments configuration (I think the previously shown fragment),  and if I then try to switch fragments, the action bar changes (also to the previously shown fragment, I think), but the shown fragment does not change.

What does **not** work:

Changing the `.add` to `.replace`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When some configurations changed, such as orientation, the app will be restarted, the the view will be recreated, `onCreate` will be called.

When the view is re-created, the ActionBar will turn to the origin state.

But if you add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"` to the `Manifest.xml`, the `onConfigurationChanged` will be called instead of `onCreate`, the view will not be re-created.

#### update1

You should keep android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize", then change the layouts after the change of screen sizes and orientation occurs, in the method: `onConfigurationChanged`.

Here are some examples: [Handling Runtime Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

Comment: So there must be a problem in the view creation after orientation change - it tries to show the wrong fragment. If onCreate is called after orientation change, then it will try to call selectItem(0) even if I am not at that position.

Comment: Yes, the method `onCreate` will be called, but `savedInstanceState` is not null, so the `selectItem(0)` will not be called.

Comment: Thanks - I will have a go at using `onConfigurationChanged`

Comment: I saw I was in your `Activity`. I send a invitation to add to as my friend in google talk, I think it would be more convenient to chat via it.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not want to have effect on the ScreenSize then you can only remove that. But if you remove to have other parameter like orientation and keyboard then it will simply load whole layout while the orientation take place.

So as i advice, just use something like below:

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|orientation"
```

with that you will get the fragment remain selected and layout will not getting updated.

Please try and let me know if its not help you.

Comment: I would like to change the layout on orientation as well so this would not solve the problem